# Duplicating / importing Xcode projects from one Mac to another

Tags: xcode

I've just purchased a new iMac and I want to duplicate / import all my Xcode projects from my old MacBook onto to it. How can this be done without setting up a SVN repository?

Both machines are at home on the same network. This should be simple but I just can't find out how...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is copy over the folder containing the project.  When you launch XCode the project path is listed under recent projects.  You can also select the project file within XCode, right click and use reveal in finder to locate the project directory.

Once you've copied the folder to your new machine, simply open the project file with XCode.

Comment: i have another issue with this u might know how to solve , 
for some reason the new computer does not have any keys in the login keychain access , when i followed the steps in the provision tool i couldn't match the certificate with any prvt key as there is nothing in the keys there ... allso the project does not run because there is 'valid certificate/prvt key in the default keychain' ?

Comment: You'll have to export your certificate from the keychain access on your old computer and save to a .p12 file.  Copy the file over to the new machine and import the .p12 file to the keychain.  I don't recall if the private key is exported when you do the certificate.  If it's not, you'll just need to expand the certificate, highlight the private key and export that seperately.

Comment: It doesn't work actually at least on Xcode 4 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800180/how-to-modify-xcode-4-project-to-be-machine-independent-like-visual-studio-or-ec