# How to modify Xcode 4 Project to be Machine independent like Visual Studio or Eclipse behave

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm very surprised not to be able to open my Xcode project on another mac, I have never that kind of problem with Visual Studio or Eclipse. I have tried this [Info.plist file "no such file" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373243/info-plist-file-no-such-file-error) but it's not enough.

I have other errors like MyAppViewController files not found in some folder whereas I checked that the files are actually there.

So how do I modify XCode 4 project so that it can be opened on any mac ?

Update: contrary to what is claimed here [Duplicating / importing Xcode projects from one Mac to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271534/duplicating-importing-xcode-projects-from-one-mac-to-another) copying isn't enough

Update 2: should I be obliged to buy that kind of tools to do so ? http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/project-duplicator-for-xcode/id467950482?mt=12

Comment: I routinely copy projects from one machine to another and have never had any issue. I use no tools other than the finder or a USB key.

Comment: Did you move rootcontroller to another folder in Xcode like me ?

Comment: I do nothing in XCode, I just quit xcode, copy everything onto a key and merge it onto the other machine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying the files over is enough, as long as you copy all files over and no files are referenced from your project file using absolute paths.

Note that you don't have to choose to have absolute paths. I'm unsure of the exact details, but I've ended up with absolute paths in projects without doing so explicitly.

For example, here's a project with a missing file:

[image: Missing file in project]

When I select the missing file, I can see that it's using an absolute path:

[image: Oops, absolute path!]

At this point, you have two options:

1. You can click the button in the bottom right of that red box I've drawn to find the file. Make sure you pick the right file; if you pick one with a different name, Xcode will happily replace `DetailViewController.m` with `SomeUnrelatedFile.m` and you'll have lost the hint about the original file. After finding it, make sure to pick **Location: Relative To Group** (usually, that'll be the right choice anyway) to avoid this happening again.
2. Possibly safer, go back to the original computer. For any file that you know is missing on the destination computer, pick **Location: Relative To Group**. Then copy everything over again.

Comment: Thanks for that full explanation will try to look back again at my project files.

Comment: I almost succeed just stuck now with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880184/could-not-read-from-info-plist :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after but it might help; I use git on  to keep my two laptops in sync with a single project. I don't have any file missing errors and it comes with all those other repository benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any tools to do this, Xcode projects can be moved, shared between other members of your team and opened on any supported machine.

There must be another problem you have, so you need to post the error.

And when you get it resolved.... using a free remote source control service such as bitbucket, would be good for you to know and get into the practice of using.